# e.response undefined at onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to execute a simple script at the `formSubmit` trigger of a form:

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  Logger.log(event);
  var d = event.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  ...
}
```

Everytime the event is triggered, i receive:

```
[14-11-20 09:10:50:315 CET] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0,126 Sekunden]
[14-11-20 09:10:50:403 CET] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0,085 Sekunden]
[14-11-20 09:10:50:411 CET] Ausführung wird gestartet
[14-11-20 09:10:50:418 CET] Logger.log([{authMode=FULL}, []]) [0 Sekunden]
[14-11-20 09:10:50:422 CET] Ausführung fehlgeschlagen: TypeError: Methode "getItemResponses" von undefined kann nicht aufgerufen werden. (Zeile 5, Datei "Code") (0.003 Sekunden Laufzeit insgesamt)
```

the script is bounded to my form and the trigger is set to "on form submit"

Where is my fault ?

Comment: I'm very late, but I just experienced this bug and it looks like a permission issue. I started from scratch on a new form and added the trigger, I had to authorize the script to access my forms and then it worked ok. Don't know how to fix it on an existing form though.

Comment: @arnaudrg was right. Google form messed up the permission somehow, all you need to do is delete and add the trigger again. The script will ask for your permission for the new trigger, so you can authorize it.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to reproduce your problem.

Tried this code on a form that has a trigger set for "onFormSubmit". Able to get the first value in variable d.

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  Logger.log(event);

  var d = event.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  Logger.log(d);

}
```

This is my Execution Transcript:

```
[14-11-20 10:37:57:103 PST] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0.078 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:250 PST] FormApp.getActiveForm() [0.079 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:312 PST] Starting execution
[14-11-20 10:37:57:316 PST] Logger.log([{response=FormResponse, source=Form,   authMode=FULL}, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:331 PST] FormResponse.getItemResponses() [0.014 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:334 PST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:334 PST] Logger.log([[----Value here----], []]) [0 seconds]
[14-11-20 10:37:57:335 PST] Execution succeeded [0.019 seconds total runtime]
```

Answer (score -1):

As of June 2020, onFormSubmit trigger does not return FormResponse object.

It actually returns a google sheet form submit event which contains the following:

> authMode
> A value from the ScriptApp.AuthMode enum.
>
> e.g. FULL

> namedValues
> An object containing the question names and values from the form submission.
>
> e.g.

```
{
  'First Name': ['Jane'],
  'Timestamp': ['6/7/2015 20:54:13'],
  'Last Name': ['Doe']
}
```

> range
> A Range object, representing the cell or range of cells that were edited.

> triggerUid
> ID of trigger that produced this event.
>
> e.g. 4034124084959907503

> values
> Array with values in the same order as they appear in the spreadsheet.
>
> e.g. ['2015/05/04 15:00', 'amin@example.com', 'Bob', '27', 'Bill',
> '28', 'Susan', '25']

ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: There are two form submit events, one for Google Sheets and another for Google Forms.